# mysqli fetch array always returns nothing

Tags: php, mysqli

My code is returning nothing. I can't understand what the problem is.

my code

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_pdf ORDER BY id DESC");

    $dataarray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {

        $dataarray [] = [
            'id'=>$row['id'],
            'ptitle'=>$row['ptitle'],
            'pdate'=>$row['pdate'],
            'filelink'=>'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'.$row['filelink'],
            'status'=>$row['status']
        ];

    }

    echo json_encode($dataarray);
```

Comment: Are you connected to correct database? This script must return at least `[]` if there are not errors.

Comment: Have you tried checking for MySQL errors?  You can't always assume your MySQL queries have worked.  `if($results === false){ die($mysqli->error); }`

Comment: P.S. It doesn't really matter but it's a good idea to be consistent on whether you are using OOP or the procedural method.  `while($row = $results->fetch_array())`

Comment: yes.database connected correctly @vp_arth

Comment: make sure you have error reporting enabled http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: Posting a live link to this page doesn't really add anything useful to the question.  The PHP's ran on the server, so all we see is the (blank) output.

Comment: That link does show a 500 so you are getting an error of some sort. Check your error logs, enable logging.

Comment: @chris85: I guess the link *was* useful then :)

Comment: It's actualy not live it's dead link =)